# how to use variable key in thymeleaf expression in js side

Tags: javascript, label, thymeleaf, expression

since few days, i tried to avoid to put an harcoded list in my JS to display a list of header labels.

I have tested many stuff but do not manage to find the way to do it.
In Html, if a put a list inside the model, the value is well interpreted by the tag th:text

```
<td th:each="header:${headerMemberLiaisonList}" th:text="#{'planner.table.header.'+ ${header}}">???planner.table.header</td>
```

The issue is that my list is not computed at this moment because it depends on the actions of the user in this view. So I try to move it in JS part.
But the same peace of code in js which should be `[[#{'planner.table.header.'+headers[i]}]]`, is not interpreted because the value between brackets is read as string.

any idea?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but I guess you want to use a Thymeleaf expression from JavaScript? That is not possible. Thymeleaf runs on the server. Once the HTML is rendered by Thymeleaf and sent to the browser, Thymeleaf can't _do_ anything anymore.

Comment: yes it is what I have also concluded from my investigation